# Why is the Prefetch object being ignored in prefetch_related?

Tags: django

Using Django 1.7:

My Queryset looks like this:

```
    return super(EmployeeViewSet, self).get_queryset()\
           .filter(status__deleted_flag=False, **filter_kwargs)\
           .prefetch_related('phone_number_set', 'email_address_set', 'street_address_set',
                             Prefetch('file_set', EmployeeFile.objects.active().select_related('content_type')))\
           .order_by('last_name', 'first_name')
```

DjDT shows the prefetch query executed

```
SELECT ••• FROM "employees_employeefile" INNER JOIN "employees_employeefiletype" 
ON ("employees_employeefile"."content_type_id" = "employees_employeefiletype"."id" )
WHERE ("employees_employeefile"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
       AND "employees_employeefile"."owner_id" IN (53, 81, ...)) 
ORDER BY "employees_employeefile"."created_at" DESC
```

Then DjDT shows each employee getting requeried for the same list of files

```
SELECT ••• FROM "employees_employeefile" 
WHERE ("employees_employeefile"."owner_id" = 53 
       AND "employees_employeefile"."deleted_at" IS NULL) 
ORDER BY "employees_employeefile"."created_at" DESC
```

They queries look the same to me, and the ModelManager method being used to do the select is the same one `(EmployeeFile.objects.active())` vs `employee.file_set.active()`

Also, I tried removing the `select_related('content_type')` just in case that was the problem